Using Keycloak for Authentication and Authorization in Spring Boot App - Policy Enforcer Config
In my spring boot application I want to use keycloak for authentication and authorization, so I wouldn't use spring security at all, I would leave everything to keycloak.
I used the following series of videos for the implementation, if anyone might be familiar with it:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHXvj3cRjbzs8TaT-RX1qJYYK2MjRro-P
Everything is working properly now, however I have a problem. In the SecurityConfig, I use a JSON file that I map to PolicyEnforcerConfig to use the Keycloak configurations during authorization and authentication.
However, the JSON file has the information hardcoded into it. How can I make it so that I don't have to explicitly define the client and realm information there, but access it from application.properties or map it from a class somehow, because as far as I know at the moment I can't use placeholders in a JSON file.
I'm open to making changes in SecurityConfig, the main thing would be to ensure that keycloak does everything afterwards.
This is my SecurityConfig class for now:
import org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.integration.jakarta.ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter;
import org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.spi.ConfigurationResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.spi.HttpRequest;
import org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.PolicyEnforcerConfig;
import org.keycloak.util.JsonSerialization;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        httpSecurity.addFilterAfter(createPolicyEnforcerFilter(), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity.sessionManagement(t -> t.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    private ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter createPolicyEnforcerFilter() {
        return new ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter(new ConfigurationResolver() {
            @Override
            public PolicyEnforcerConfig resolve(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
                try {
                    return JsonSerialization.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/policy-enforcer.json"),
                            PolicyEnforcerConfig.class);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

And this is the policy-enforcer.json:
{
  "realm": "realm-name",
  "auth-server-url": "server-url",
  "resource": "client-name",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "client-secret"
  },
  "http-method-as-scope": true,
  "paths": [
    {
      "path": "/path-1",
      "enforcement-mode": "DISABLED"
    },
    {
      "path": "/path-2",
      "enforcement-mode": "DISABLED"
    }
  ]
}

With this implementation everything works fine, but I don't think it's the best to hardcode the client data.

Hope that you are aware of all the "cons" of using such a delegated access control...

Hi, I'd like you to explain, as I think I'm not clear about it, as I'm a beginner and this is my first time with security and also with keycloak

You should not have unsecured resource servers. You can't unit-test Keycloak policies, at least not as easily as you can test access control on Spring resource servers. Keycloak policies can change at runtime (someone can edit it in prod), opening wide security breaches. Setting access control rules like Can edit a message if is granted with "MODERATOR" role or if is the author of the message is a mess with  Keycloak policies, when it is trivial with Spring security (it is not the responsibility of Keycloak to know business entities structure).

And also this adds latency to requests and puts useless pressure on the authorization server: each and every request to you API will trigger an internal request to the authorization server.

Then are you suggesting that it's better to use keycloak in a way that it's responsible for authentication (frontend client in keycloak), but I'm supposed to handle authorization with spring security? We came up with this solution (we currently have two clients in keycloak, an FE client responsible for authentication and a BE client that handles authorization with policies and roles) because it was the best way to customize the access strategy for the client, considering its specific needs.

"because it was the best way to customize the access strategy for the client." Based on what exactly? "handle authorization with spring security?" Yes. a resource server is responsible for giving access to resources. It best knows about this resources structure and is responsible for enforcing business rules. Who can access a resource and what (s)he can do with it is part of this rules decided by the "business". Spring Security is flexible enough to implement about any access control rule.

Thanks for the advice, I have modified it as you suggested! It is much easier and straightforward now.

You can build a policy enforcer configuration object using the same values in your json file instead of using a json file and then use placeholders for whichever values you want in your code ensuring you have the placeholder values defined.
The example below mimics your json file by using such an approach.

    //...imports and other annotations omitted for brevity

    //assign placeholder values
    @Value("${my-app.keycloak.auth.server.url}")
    String SERVER_URL;

    @Value("${my-app.keycloak.realm}")
    String REALM;

    @Value("${my-app.keycloak.client.name}")
    String RESOURCE;

    @Value("${my-app.keycloak.client.secret}")
    String CLIENT_SECRET;

    //... other configurations ommitted for brevity

    //build policy enforcer config
    private ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter createPolicyEnforcerFilter() {

        PolicyEnforcerConfig config = new PolicyEnforcerConfig();
        PathConfig path1Config = new PathConfig(),
        path2Config = new PathConfig();

        path1Config.setPath("/path-1");
        path1Config.setEnforcementMode(EnforcementMode.DISABLED);

        path2Config.setPath("/path-2");
        path2Config.setEnforcementMode(EnforcementMode.DISABLED);

        config.setAuthServerUrl(SERVER_URL);
        config.setRealm(REALM);
        config.setResource(RESOURCE);
        config.setCredentials(Map.of("secret", CLIENT_SECRET));
        config.setHttpMethodAsScope(true);
        config.setEnforcementMode(EnforcementMode.ENFORCING);
        config.setPaths(List.of(path1Config,path2Config));

        return new ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter(new ConfigurationResolver() {
            @Override
            public PolicyEnforcerConfig resolve(HttpRequest request) {
                return config;
            }
        });


In the application.properties set the following.
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8081/realms/medium

On the SecurityConfig, it looks as follows.
@Bean
 public SecurityFilterChain configurePaths(HttpSecurity http,
   @Value("${security.authentication.unsecure.paths}") List<String> springSecurityAllowedPaths)
   throws Exception {
  AntPathRequestMatcher[] allowedPaths = springSecurityAllowedPaths.stream().map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new)
    .toArray(AntPathRequestMatcher[]::new);

  http.sessionManagement(
    sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
  http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests -> authorizeHttpRequests.requestMatchers(allowedPaths)
    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated());

  http.oauth2ResourceServer(
    oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())));

  return http.build();
}

Source: Secure your application with Spring Security and Keycloak

Thanks for the answer, but in our case we can't use it, because we don't use spring security, only keycloak, for both authentication and authorization.
